# How to use blocks for attribute in django

Tags: django, templates

I want to use jinja2 blocks for attribute in django. Basically on every page I want a different url for a header image. This is the `base.html`:

```
<header id="masthead" style="background-image:url('{% block headerimage %}{% endblock %}'"
. . .
```

How do I pass in '`{% static 'img/some-bg.jpeg' %}` to it from `index.html` which `{% extends "base.html" %}`? I tried to use this block syntax I just showed and it does now work. How do I achieve this? I want to pass in a string for the url of an image from a template that inherits from the base template. Thank you :-).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the header gonna be in every page of your site use context processors

```
# app/context_processors.py
from django.contrib.staticfiles.templatetags.staticfiles import static

def get_image_header_url(request):
    d = {
        reverse('home'): static("images/home.jpg"), # {% static "images/image.jpeg" %}
        reverse('about'): "url_of_image/about.jpg",
        reverse('contact'): "url_of_image/contact.jpg",
        ...
    }
    return {'header_img_url' : d[request.path]}
```

In case you want to display random images

```
# app/context_processors.py
import random
def get_random_header_url(request):
       image_urls = ['url/image1.jpeg', 'url/image2.jpeg']
       return {"header_img_url" : random.choice(image_urls)}
```

define the context_processor in the `settings.py`

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        .....
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                ....
                "django.template.context_processors.i18n",
                'add.context_processors.get_random_header_url',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

And use it in your html file

```
<header id="masthead" style="{{ header_img_url }}"
...
```

In case you want to load static images

```
from django.contrib.staticfiles.templatetags.staticfiles import static
static_img_url = static("images/image.jpeg"); # {% static "images/image.jpeg" %}
```

Comment: Thanks! But I dont understand what I would replace `your_random_url` with. Could you help me out a bit?

Comment: Would I put the `background-image` style attribute there? The problem is that I will have a different bg image for each page. I do not quite understand the answer.

Comment: Yes you have to put there the urls of your images and choose from them a random one in case you want a random

Comment: OK thanks! Also a noob question: how do I pass in static image url from the view function directly?

Comment: Like using the `{% static %}` tag

Comment: See the answer now